# Equivalent of WAIT_ABANDONED in C++11 threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, c++11

I'm rewriting code that uses WinAPI for threading to use the new standard threading libraries.

I was wondering what would be the equivalent way in C++11 to notice that a mutex was abandoned or lost.

The following code has to "outsource" an initialization procedure to the created thread, but should not return until it's done and knows the result of initialization.

```
bool Foo::Example()
{
    m_thread = std::thread(&Foo::ThreadProc, this);

    // wait for event before waiting for mutex
    WaitForSingleObject(m_hEvent, INFINITE);
    ResetEvent(m_hEvent);

    // the thread aquired the mutex. now wait until it is released or abandoned
    DWORD ret = WaitForSingleObject(m_hMutex, INFINITE);
    ReleaseMutex(m_hMutex);

    // check the result
    if (ret == WAIT_ABANDONED)
        return false;
    return true;
}
void Foo::ThreadProc()
{
    // aquire mutex and signal that it's done
    WaitForSingleObject(m_hMutex, INFINITE);
    SetEvent(m_hEvent);

    // ... initialization (required to be in this thread)

    if (initializationfailure)
        return; // failure. mutex is abandoned

    // success. mutex is unlocked
    ReleaseMutex(m_hMutex);

    // ... do the work
}
```

What would be a replacement for the WAIT_ABANDONED check? I didn't find anything in std::mutex. It even says `The behavior is undefined if the mutex is not unlocked before being destroyed, i.e. some thread still owns it.` Is there no equivalent? Anything in std threading library that comes close to this?

I also take suggestions in improoving the code. It seems to be too much synchronization for such a simple task.

Comment: There's no equivalent in the **standard** (as should be very clear from the wording you quote). That is, you cannot do this portably. It's possible that a particular implementation might offer support for this feature, *somehow*, but the resulting program would be in "undefined behavior" land, and once you're there anything goes.

Comment: Using WAIT_ABANDONED intentionally is a bad mistake, it should always be reserved to signal serious threading bugs in the code.  If you use the Microsoft implementation for std::mutex then you'll get something completely different, it doesn't use an OS mutex.  It is built on top of the ConcRT library.  Which re-implements the synchronization primitives from scratch.  You'll get an assert when the std::mutex object is deleted and still holds a lock.  Only in the debug build, silent failure in the release build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no equivalent.  You could use RAII to unlock the mutex and avoid abandoning it in the first place, then you don't need to be able to test for it.

You could use a future instead of waiting on an event and using a mutex, which makes it much simpler than error-prone explicit synchronisation:

```
bool Foo::Example()
{
    std::promise<bool> p;
    auto res = p.get_future();
    m_thread = std::thread(&Foo::ThreadProc, this, std::ref(p));
    return res.get();
}
void Foo::ThreadProc(std::promise<bool>& p)
{
    // ... initialization (required to be in this thread)

    if (initializationfailure)
    {
        p.set_value(false); // failure.
        return;
    }

    p.set_value(true);

    // IMPORTANT: p is a dangling reference now!

    // ... do the work
}
```

The main thread will block until the promise is fulfilled, and then returns true or false depending on whether the initialization worked.

You could avoid the dangling reference by making it `ThreadProc(std::promise<bool> p)` and then pass it as `std::move(p)` instead of `std::ref(p)` but I don't think the `std::thread` in Visual C++ supports perfect forwarding of move-only types.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't really solve the problem. I need to wait for the initialization but at the same time signal success or failure.

Comment: @typ1232, I've added an alternative that is much simpler than relying on abandoned mutexes

Comment: @typ1232: If you need to signal success or failure, just use an extra variable for that.  You should *not* be using abandoned vs. not abandoned to communicate program state.  The `WAIT_ABANDONED` status is an "oh crap, something went horribly, *horribly* wrong, better to bail out as fast as possible right now" flag, not something that should ever occur during normal program operation.